# I need to find .c files a specified directory

Tags: shell

I have directory named `dir/sub_dir` and in that directory I have `*.c` files:

```
add_num.c
sub_num.c
mul_num.c
div_num.h
exp.txt
```

and If I found any files I have to use it in If statement. Like

```
If any name is found means ok Else no files found
```

How to use in If statement?

Comment: fix gramma and format the pseudo code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` or any other utility that provides a usable return based on whether any files matching `'*.c'` are found. `ls` works equally well:

```
if ls "$dir"/*.c >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "have .c files"
else
    echo "no .c files"
fi
```

where `$dir` contains the desired path. As a *one-liner*:

```
if ls "$dir"/*.c >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo "have .c files"; else echo "no .c files"; fi
```

---

**A Generalized Version For Any Dir/Any Extension**

You can easily make the script a general extension search by allowing user input of the directory to be searched and the extension to be found. The script below is a generalized version that by *default* searches the present directory for `.c` files, but will search for any directory entered as the first argument and any extension entered as the second argument:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=${1:-.}
ext=${2:-c}

if ls "$dir"/*."$ext" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    printf "have .%s files\n" "$ext"
else
    printf "no .%s files\n" "$ext"
fi
```

**Examples**

```
$ bash ~/scr/utl/search_ext.sh debug txt
have .txt files

$ ls -l1 debug/*.txt
debug/array.txt
debug/data.txt

$ bash ~/scr/utl/search_ext.sh debug foo
no .foo files
```

(there are no `.foo` files)

---

**Detect if Non `.c` Extensions Also Present**

That changes things a bit, but to determine if a directory has files other than files with the `.c` extensions, you will have to check each file. In POSIX shell, you have the `expr string : regex` feature available to check patterns. (In bash there are a couple of different ways to do this). The following will do what you are looking for:

```
for i in "$dir"/*; do ## test that each is a 'file' and has .c ext
    if [ -f "$i" -a $(expr "$i" : ".*.c") -eq 0 ]; then 
        echo "non '.c' files"  ## print error & exit on non .c file
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo "have .c files"  ## we are here -- they are all .c files
```

---

**Using Bash Parameter Expansion**

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=${1:-.}

for i in "$dir"/*; do ## test that each is a 'file' and has .c ext
    if [ -f "$i" -a ${i##*.} != "c" ]; then 
        echo "non '.c' files"  ## print error & exit on non .c file
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo "have .c files"  ## we are here -- they are all .c files
```

This will be faster than the POSIX use of `expr`.

---

**Prompting for Search Directory**

Your code you posted did not make much sense. (and there were numerous missing `';'` and `done` statements, and you never used `path`) There is no need to change to the directory that the user enters. If you do, as you did in your code, you must change the second loop. Here is an update that prompts for the search directory and will exit if a sub-directory is present in the search path:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "enter path: "
read -r dir

dir=${dir%/}  ## check/trim trailing '/'

if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then    ## validate dir exists
    echo "error: No such directory '$dir'"
    exit 1
fi

for i in "$dir"/*; do ## test that each is a 'file' and has .c ext
    ## if you want to exit if a subdir exists, just add -d test
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        echo "subdirectory present"
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ -f "$i" -a ${i##*.} != "c" ]; then 
        echo "non '.c' files"  ## print error & exit on non .c file
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo "have .c files"  ## we are here -- they are all .c files
```

You can tailor that as you like.

Comment: Hi David Thank u.But your code only checks for .c files if any other files are there means exp-.txt,.csv n all it has to show me the error

Comment: *along wit that .c files

Comment: Sure, just change the `.c` in the test to anything you want. You could even make it `if ls "$1"/*."$2" >/dev/null 2>&1; then` and have it search the dir and extension provided on the command line. e.g. (`bash scriptname somedir txt` - to search `somedir` for `*.txt` files) I would use e.g. `printf "have .%s files\n" "$2"` in that case so the messages reflect the extension searched for.

Comment: Hey @David C. RankIn let me clear.I need to search in the Directory for .c files only If any other extensions are found along with means it has to generate error message

Comment: Ahh -- got you. that radically changes the approach. Since we are limited to POSIX shell (not bash), you will use the `expr string : regex` to test if each file has a `.c` extension. If you have a large number of files, we can look at a faster approach.

Comment: i m using bash pls help me in tat

Comment: OK, done, wish I would have known from the beginning -- much faster/easier.

Comment: Hey @David C. RankIn m getting this error.when copy your code

Comment: That's strange, I just copied/pasted the code again and ran it without any problems. How are you running the code? You either make the script executable (e.g. `chmod 0755 scriptname` and run it as `./scriptname /path/to/dir` (or leave path blank for current dir); or without making it executable you run it with `bash scriptname /path/to/dir` (or leave path blank for current dir)). No tricks. Are you on a Mac? The *unexpected end of file* would mean it isn't seeing a `fi` or `done` most likely (or you forgot to leave a space on each side of `[ stuff ]` Otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Since you have bash, change the test to `if [[ -f "$i" && ${i##*.} != "c" ]]; then` or `if [[ -f "$i" ]] && [[ ${i##*.} != "c" ]]; then` if you are on a Mac. I'm not certain they support all variations of the test constructs. (they may, just not sure)

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo "Enter dir path : "
read path
set `echo $path | tr '/'' '`
for dir in $*
do
if [ -d $dir ]
then
        echo "Directory is  present"
        cd $dir
elif [ -f $dir ]
then
         "There is a file"
         exit 1
else
        echo "Given Direcory doesn't exists"
        exit 1
fi
for i in "$dir"/*; do
  if [ -f "$i" -a ${i##*.} != "c" ]; then
        echo "non '.c' files"
        exit 1
  fi
done
echo "Have .c files"

Comment: OK, hold on. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Thank u very much @David its working now..Thanks a lot again

Comment: Glad I could help. If you are serious about scripting, there are several good howtos  [**Bash Guide for Beginners**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html) and [**Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) both are worth working through. Then there is the [**Bash Guide and Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) for everything else.

Comment: Hey @David if i have to find the file in directory according to divisions and extension what i have to write in IF command

Comment: exp- format1_format2_format3.h here we have to extract the file name and compare the formats If right format is ter then it is Ok.Otherwise KO.

Comment: Ok, sorry been busy with my real job. Extracting the filename is easy enough. if `var=filename.c`, you want `fnvar=${var%.*}` which will yield `fnvar=filename` (it does require the file actually has an extension). That should give you both parts.

Comment: what i need is i have different file names sepaated by '_' exp- field1_field2_field3.c.If i have to extract field 1&2 means how i have to write the script.Pls suggest asap

Comment: You can use a combination of either `var=field1_field2_field3.c` with `new=${var%_*}` (removes from the *right* up to *first* `'_'` giving `new=field1_field2`) or `new=${var#*_}` (removes from the *left* up to *first* `'_'` giving `new=field2_field3.c`) while `new=${var%%_*}` (removes from the *right* up to *last* `'_'` (`new=field1`) ) and `new=${var##*_}` (removes from the *left* up to *last* `'_'` giving `new=field3.c`) Note the position of the `'*'` in each.